# Discord.py saying "Improper token passed" while deploying to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bots, discord, discord.py

https://github.com/thmaula/giveawaydiscord

That is where all the code is.

So I try to deploy my discord bot on heroku using github intergration, and time and again it says "Improper token passed". I have tried to surround in double brackets, regenerated the token again, and yes, i AM using the token and not client ID. It is just confusing as to why discord.py would say this when the token is correct

Anyone have any suggestions?

This is the traceback(note that it works fine outside of heroku in python 3.5, but IN heroku because it doesn't support 3.5 it runs on 3.6, and that's when it fails) :

```
2020-01-02T00:00:26.653880+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-02T00:00:26.653882+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "start.py", line 561, in <module>
2020-01-02T00:00:26.654209+00:00 app[worker.1]:     bot.run(config.token)
2020-01-02T00:00:26.654214+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 519, in run
2020-01-02T00:00:26.654516+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
2020-01-02T00:00:26.654519+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 488, in run_until_complete
2020-01-02T00:00:26.654798+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return future.result()
2020-01-02T00:00:26.654799+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 490, in start
2020-01-02T00:00:26.655083+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from self.login(*args, **kwargs)
2020-01-02T00:00:26.655086+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 416, in login
2020-01-02T00:00:26.655329+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from getattr(self, '_login_' + str(n))(*args, **kwargs)
2020-01-02T00:00:26.655332+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 346, in _login_1
2020-01-02T00:00:26.655646+00:00 app[worker.1]:     data = yield from self.http.static_login(token, bot=is_bot)
2020-01-02T00:00:26.655662+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 262, in static_login
2020-01-02T00:00:26.655941+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from e
2020-01-02T00:00:26.655958+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
2020-01-02T00:00:26.667944+00:00 app[worker.1]: Unclosed client session
2020-01-02T00:00:26.667983+00:00 app[worker.1]: client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fc1648ef9e8>
2020-01-02T00:00:26.743930+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have leaked your token by putting it on a public GitHub. Please either make the GitHub private or find a different way to store the token. Secondly, try just putting the token in a text file or in a cloud database such as MongoDB and reading the token from there.

If none of those solutions sound good to you, and you want to keep the ini file, make sure you add a variable to the read version of config in [config.py](https://github.com/thmaula/giveawaydiscord/blob/master/config.py)